# Command not found error when initializing the tiller using `helm init`

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to use Kubernetes cluster with Kubernetes Helm chart for defining the Kubernetes services and deployment. I installed Helm client on one machine by using the following command,

```
sudo snap install helm --classic
```

And I accessed the Kubernetes cluster master node and trying to run `helm init` command. But when I am running I am getting the error,

```
helm: command not found
```

And when I am checking Kubernetes cluster installation, kubectl commands are properly running.

For the "command not found", how can I solve my Kubernetes Helm Tiller initialization issue?

Comment: Where did you install helm and from where are you running the helm command?

Comment: installed helm in one base vm. And tried to run the helm inti in master node of kubernetes cluster. I want to use helm client in separate machine where I am planning to make control node.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to run `helm init` on the same machine where you installed the helm client. That will install tiller on the Kubernetes cluster you have configured on your kubeconfig.

There are two parts of Helm, the Client (what is called `helm`) and the server (called `tiller`).

`Tiller` runs (most of the times) on your Kubernetes cluster and manages the releases (the `charts` you deploy).

`Helm` runs on your local machine, CI/CD or where you want.

Helm is also used for deploying `tiller` into your K8S cluster. This happens when you execute `helm init` and by default it'll create a kubernetes deployment called `tiller-deploy` on the `kube-system` namespace. This `tiller` deployment is what the `helm` client will use as a server.

Helm discovers automatically where to install `tiller` by checking your kubeconfig (`~/.kube/config`) file and by default it will use the selected context there.

You always use the `helm` cli from your local machine or CI/CD you don't use it from your Kubernetes master(s).

Edit: This was true for Helm v2, now with Helm v3 tiller no longer exists, the deployment of the chart is done by the `helm` client itself and `helm init` is no longer necessary.

https://helm.sh/blog/helm-3-released/

Comment: Currently I installed helm client on my control node machine. This machine is not in kubernetes cluster. I thought that helm client need to install in any control machine and tiller need to install inside cluster. But If I using helm init in the machine where I installed helm client , then how tiller going to install in kubernetes cluster ? I did not understood.Can you give idea please ? Thank you for your response Mr Esteban Garcia.

Comment: @Jacob I've added some more information to my answer. Hope it clarifies it for you.

Comment: Yes. I got the idea. Thank you for your proper response.

Comment: I have one more doubt on this. I am not able to find the config file .kube/config in my machine , even if I installed helm client. Where I can find this config file?

Comment: You need to have `kubectl` installed - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/

Comment: So can I configure kubectl outside of cluster like my local machine/ my base vm ?

Comment: `kubectl` is the kubernetes client and you can use it from anywhere you would like to interact with your cluster(s).

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that helm is installed with `sudo snap install helm`.

If installed, you should have something like that:

```
snap "helm" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'
```

2. If helm is installed, then at the end of the file ~/.profile, add the following:

```
# Addition of snap packages to PATH
PATH="$PATH:/snap/bin/"
```

3. Log Out / Log In to update the changes to `~/.profile`
4. Check that the `helm` command works by testing it: `helm version`

If you still encounter the `Command not found` message, go to Preferences > Profile > Command and check `Run command as a login shell` if not checked.

Answer (score 0):

In the Kubernetes 1.6 RBAC is enabled by default which makes helm harder to run tiller shamelessly so that based on the decision of community tiller is removed for Helm 3 onwards. Checkout official blog for [more details](https://helm.sh/blog/helm-3-preview-pt2/#helm)